# Filemaker Invoice Layout Body not expanding for more than one lineitem position

Tags: layout, filemaker, invoices

I know this is a very basic question but I am simply stuck here. I should be beyond this problem but i can't find a way.

Tables:

- Customers (pk)
- Invoices (pk, Customersfk)
- InvoiceLineItems (Invoicefk,Servicesfk)
- Services (pk)

In my invoice print layout I have a leading and a following grand summary. Inbetween those I have my body. In that body I have the amount (lineitems), the description (services), unit price (services) and sub sum (lineitems).

It works fine, for one lineitem, but when I have more than one lineitem for one invoice the body doesn't expand. Filemaker online help says the following:

> Body: Each object you put in the body, including fields, text objects, and graphics, appears once for each record in the found set. You can have only one body in a layout.

The print layout shows records from invoices. When I make a portal big enough for the entries it shows all positions.

There must be a tiny thing I overlook. I tried to analyse the starter solutions, checked the relationships and compared the layout options in the inspector. So far no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The print layout shows records from invoices.

That is a mistake. Your print layout should be based on the InvoiceLineItems table.

To print an invoice, you need a script that goes to related record (from InvoiceLineItems, Show only related records). Thus you'll have a found set of the selected invoice's line items, which you will print out in list view. Place the invoice's details in the sub-summary parts. Do not use portals for printing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed the dependence to lineitems, however I now got the problem that it has two found records but displays them independantly instead of all in one layout. Also when I use the script step to go to the layout and show only related records, I ahve the same issue.

Comment: @Sarnu As I said, your print layout needs to be in **list view**.